# Python module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictReader'

Tags: python-3.x, csv

So I am following a Python for [Data Science Course](https://www.coursera.org/learn/python-data-analysis/home/welcome) on Coursera. I have linked this in case anyone is interested.

They have a Jupyter Notebook to follow along, but I prefer to code in Notepad++ ("NPP") and write it all from scratch as it helps me learn better.

The following code I have literally copy and pasted into NPP

```
import csv

with open('mpg.csv') as csvfile:
    mpg = list(csv.DictReader(csvfile))

print(mpg[:3])
```

But when I try to run the file, I am getting the following AttributeError

```
AttributeError: module 'csv' has no attribute 'DictReader'
```

I am not entirely sure why as I have seen this is indeed a module according to [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#module-contents), and obviously it works on the Jupyter Notebook on Coursera

Something that I thought may be of note is the location in which I saved the 'mpg.csv' file. I have saved it in the same folder (directory?) that the python file is in. But obviously if the location was a problem It wouldn't be throwing out an AttributeError would it?

Thanks in advance for assistance.

Comment: If you called any of your files `csv.py`, don't call them that.

Comment: I just looked, it was indeed named csv.py ! Changed the name to something else and the code runs with no error! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 25):

Did you happen to name your Python file csv.py? Don't do that! :)

You should avoid naming Python files as keywords or classes.

Answer (score 1):

change Dictreader to DictReader

i have also started that course.

Best of luck!